# Would a block of doped semiconductor connected to a metal wire gain electric charge?

Tags: electrons, semiconductor-physics

Consider a block of negatively doped semiconductor connected to a large section of metal wire.

*(I am assuming a negatively doped semiconductor for specificity, while implying a similar, though reverse, effect with a positively doped block.)*

- Is it correct to think that the electron gas pressure in the semiconductor is somewhat elevated and, therefore, given an opportunity, electrons would tend to rather leave than enter, thus creating a slight positive electric charge in the semiconductor and a slight negative charge in the surrounding wiring?
- Would the same effect persist in a circuit if electric current is flowing through the semiconductor block?
- Assuming such effect does manifest, how would it be quantitatively estimated?

Answer (score 0):

It is called a Schottky barrier. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky barrier.

There is charge transfer. The metal induces gap states which are then occupied by electrons: " the chemical termination of the semiconductor crystal against a metal creates electron states within its band gap. The nature of these metal-induced gap states and their occupation by electrons".

Comment: This article does not directly answer my question, does it?

Comment: I extended my answer in case for some reason or another you don't read the article.

Comment: I simply need an answer laid out in the terms of the question. The way you _(or, rather, the resource you are quoting)_ put it, it is not helpful to me. I can see the usefulness of that article in some other regards, but it _does not directly answer my question_.

Comment: If you could be bothered to actually answer my questions in your own words? Surely it would help me so much. You can start with either confirming or denying the existence of the effect I described, and then also confirm my explanation via electron gas pressure or explain why it is wrong and then put forward your own, perhaps in terms of electron states. This way an excellent answer may be created.